# How to run Jetbrains gateway headlessly?

Tags: remote-debugging, jetbrains-ide, goland, jetbrains-gateway

I am trying to install Jetbrains gateway on a machine which has no graphics environment, nor an internet connection. My situation is similar to [scenario 3](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/jetbrains-gateway.html) in this regard.

I have manually installed the gateway from the .tar.gz file.

Now upon trying to run the gateway script per the instructions with ./gateway.sh, I get the error: `Startup Error Unable to detect graphics environment.`

I assume there is a way to run it headlessly, I just haven't been able to find any information. My goal is to connect goland to the server to debug some processes I cannot easily mock on my own system.

Answer (score 2):

I presume you want to develop/debug something in a remote environment from your local machine.

If so, JetBrains Gateway should be installed on the local machine. It can connect to a remote environment, deploy Goland there, and attach a JetBrains Client to it.

Does this work for you?